# Finding the center of mass in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

Here is my image:
[image]

I want to find the center of mass in this image. I can find the approximate location of the center of mass by drawing two perpendicular lines as shown in this image:
[image]

I want to find it using an image processing tool in python. I have a little experience in the image processing library of python (scikit-image) but, I am not sure if this library could help finding the center of mass in my image.
I was wondering if anybody could help me to do it. I will be happy if it is possible to find the center of mass in my image using any other library in python.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site where you can put requests for code.

Comment: Request a code?! Please read my question carefully and let me know where I requested a code. I just asked for help.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `skimage.measure.moments` (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html)

Comment: I took a look at it but I did not get it right. Is it possible to provide a very simple example for example finding the enter of a square or circle in an image so I can learn how to implement it in my image?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`skimage.measure.regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) will do what you want. Here's an example:

```
import imageio as iio
from skimage import filters
from skimage.color import rgb2gray  # only needed for incorrectly saved images
from skimage.measure import regionprops

image = rgb2gray(iio.imread('eyeball.png'))
threshold_value = filters.threshold_otsu(image)
labeled_foreground = (image > threshold_value).astype(int)
properties = regionprops(labeled_foreground, image)
center_of_mass = properties[0].centroid
weighted_center_of_mass = properties[0].weighted_centroid

print(center_of_mass)
```

On my machine and with your example image, I get `(228.48663375508113, 200.85290046969845)`.

We can make a pretty picture:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import label2rgb

colorized = label2rgb(labeled_foreground, image, colors=['black', 'red'], alpha=0.1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(colorized)
# Note the inverted coordinates because plt uses (x, y) while NumPy uses (row, column)
ax.scatter(center_of_mass[1], center_of_mass[0], s=160, c='C0', marker='+')
plt.show()
```

That gives me this output:

[image: eye center of mass]

You'll note that there's some bits of foreground that you probably don't want in there, like at the bottom right of the picture. That's a whole nother answer, but you can look at `scipy.ndimage.label`, `skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects`, and more generally at `skimage.segmentation`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass.html#scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass) function to find the center of mass of an object.

For example, using this question's image:

```sh
wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffDLD.jpg
```

```py
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import scipy.ndimage as ndi

img = mpimg.imread('ffDLD.jpg')
img = img.mean(axis=-1).astype('int')  # in grayscale

cy, cx = ndi.center_of_mass(img)

print(cy, cx)
```

```sh
228.75223713169711 197.40991592129836
```

Comment: Consider including the image you use and include the output of the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about **[Image Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment)**.

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) there's a tutorial of how use it with opencv and python

Comment: please add some information to your answer. just providing links will render your answer useless once the links are dead.