# Finding the center of mass of an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

[image]I have a grey scale image and would like to find the centre of mass (centre of intensity) of this image. I don't want to find the mean value across of each axis.

So I have a 2D array which represents the intensity of this image along the horizontal and vertical axis. The centre of mass is obviously where the  white dot is but i don't manage to find a way to calculate it's coordinates.

The results I obtain are always wrong.[My results are *750* along the horizontal line and *454* along the vertical. The white dot centre coordinates are *520* along the horizontal axis and *430* along the vertical ! [image]

Here is what I tried :

`img` is the 2D array which represents the intensity of this image. Its a 1024 row, 1280 columns array. How can i find the centre of mass of this image pls ?

```py
intensite_total = np.sum(img)#This contains the sum of each element from the img matrix

X = np.linspace(0,1023,1024)
print(X)
print(np.shape(X))
print(np.shape(X))

x_bary = np.sum(np.dot(X,img))/intensite_total

print(x_bary)


print("YYYYYYYYYYYYYY")

Y = np.linspace(0,1279,1280)
print(Y)
print(np.shape(Y))
print(np.shape(np.dot(img,Y)))

y_bary = np.sum(np.dot(img,Y))/intensite_total

print(y_bary)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have more familiarity with computer vision and this looks like something [cv2.minMaxLoc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707) can help with. Doing a quick search I see [alternatives using skimage and scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888239/finding-the-center-of-mass-in-an-image). It is unclear whether you are allowed to simply use a library or this is part of a tutorial/lesson where you need to implement this yourself using numpy alone. HTH

Comment: The [tag:center] and [tag:mass] tags do not seem relevant here.

Comment: Is the image exactly zero away from the dot? If there is an offset to the intensities then the center of mass will be shifted.

Comment: Please also provide your actual image, without axes, annotation and borders so we can actually analyse it.

Comment: My bad. I added my actual image.

Comment: Have you considered using `cv2.moments()`? See example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72190703/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of mass is found by computing its integral. For this you need two coordinate arrays, weight the data with the coordinate arrays and sum:

```py
import numpy as np

image = np.random.random((100, 200))

x = np.arange(image.shape[1])
y = np.arange(image.shape[0])
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

A = image.sum()

# Center of mass
x_cms = (xx * image).sum() / A
y_cms = (yy * image).sum() / A

print(x_cms, y_cms)
```

Which prints:

```
99.30012423254516 49.62527469708466
```

UPDATE:

I double checked and this gives the same result as your code:

```py
A = np.sum(image)

X = np.linspace(0, image.shape[1] - 1, image.shape[1])

x_cms = np.sum(np.dot(image, X)) / A

Y = np.linspace(0, image.shape[0] - 1, image.shape[0])

y_cms = np.sum(np.dot(Y, image)) / A
print(x_cms, y_cms)
```

Which prints:

```
99.30012423254516 49.62527469708466
```

UPDATE 2:

I took a closer look at the data and plotting on logarithmic scale, one can see that the background is not empty:

[image]

A simple threshold of the data like `image[image < 20] = 0`, leads to the expected result:

```py
521.9619304953782 430.8132321823475
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This code works with a sqare matrix. But mine is a rectangle, and it doesn't work. Jupyter says : 

16 
     17 
---> 18 x_cms = (x1 * img).sum() / intensite_total
     19 y_cms = (y1 * img).sum() / intensite_total
     20 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1024,) (1024,1280)

Comment: I updated the code to and added an example along the lines of your code.

Comment: My bad, i think i confused x and xx when I tried your code. Thank you very much for your answer. 

Anyway like you said it gives the same result. Wich makes me wonder if the center of mass should really be in the center of the white dot ?

Comment: Indeed, I updated my answer. There is low brightness background emission, which moves the center of mass from the expected bright position. A simple thresholding leads to the expected result. To choose the appropriate background handling / subtraction one would need the context of the data.

Comment: This is it, the background level makes the method not useful on the raw image. @Camille I would remove the background by estimating it (eg an opening with a large SE, or fitting a quadratic function), before computing the center of mass.